# Sind "o. ä." und "o. Ä." unterschiedlich?

Tags: difference, capitalization, abbreviation

Ich glaube, dass *o. Ä.* mit Substantiven und *o. ä.* mit Adjektiven benutzt wird. Aber [Wiktionarys](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/o._%C3%A4.) Beispiele tun dies nicht.

Sind *o. ä.* und *o. Ä.* unterschiedlich?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually, Wiktionary does distinguish:

[o. ä.](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/o._%C3%A4.) vs. [o. Ä.](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/o._%C3%84.)

> o. ä. = oder ähnlich = or similar,
>
> o. Ä. = oder Ähnliche(s) = or similar (things etc.)

Comment: Oh lordy. It's people vs things, not nouns vs adjectives. Now I just feel silly. Thank you though. Aside from that, is there any difference between them?

Comment: No, you were right: o. ä. = oder ähnlich = or similar, whereas o. Ä. = oder Ähnliche(s) = or similar (things etc.)

Comment: @Mirov With the sole exception of abstractly referring personal pronouns the German language **never** distinguishes between people and things or living and non-living things.

Comment: @Ingmar: Warum antwortest du auf Englisch, wenn die Frage auf Deutsch gestellt wurde?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Warum ist Dir das 3 ¼ Jahre später einen Kommentar wert?

Comment: @Ingmar: Weil ich das vorgestern zum ersten Mal gesehen habe, und für einen neuen Beitrag hielt. Aus irgend einem Grund, den ich nicht nachvollziehen kann, erscheinen nämlich manchmal Uraltbeiträge auf der Startseite von german.stackexchange.com, und wenn man dann nicht aufs Datum schaut (mache ich selten), hält man die dann eben für neu.

Answer (score 8):

Im Grunde ist es so, wie es der OP ja schon angedeutet hat:

***o.ä.*** oder ***oder ähnliche[s|n|m|r]*** mit der adjektivischen Form wird kleingeschrieben.

duden.de bringt [folgendes Beispiel](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/aehnlich):

> Hüte, Mützen o.ä. Kopfbedeckungen [‚oder ähnliche‘]

***o.Ä.*** oder ***oder Ähnliche[s|n|m|r]*** mit der substantivierten Form wird großgeschrieben.

[Beispiel von duden.de](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/aehnlich):

> Hüte, Mützen o.Ä. [‚oder Ähnliches‘]

Siehe auch [Groß- und Kleinschreibung von Adjektiven](https://de.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Verzeichnis:Deutsch/Rechtschreibung/Gro%C3%9F-_und_Kleinschreibung_von_Adjektiven) in Wiktionary.

Aber nicht alle Adjektive, denen kein Substantiv folgt, sind substantiviert:

„Adjektive, die sich auf ein vorhergehendes oder nachstehendes Substantiv beziehen […]“ werden kleingeschrieben ([Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Verzeichnis:Deutsch/Rechtschreibung/Gro%c3%9f-_und_Kleinschreibung_von_Adjektiven#Kleinschreibung)).

Das kann gelegentlich<sup>1</sup> auch für unseren Fall relevant sein, z.B.:

> Getränke wie Pepsi, Fanta o.ä., deren Hauptbestandteil Zucker ist,
>   sollten gemieden werden. [‚oder ähnliche‘]

<sub>Man kann sich das auch als Auslassung veranschaulichen: *[…], Fanta oder ähnliche Getränke, deren […]*</sub>

---

1: Häufiger kommt hier *u.a.* ‚und andere‘ vor.

Comment: Bei mehrteiligen Abkürzungen (o. ä., o. Ä., z. B., u. a.) wird zwischen den einzelnen Elementen ein Zwischenraum gesetzt.

Comment: @Loong: Du sprichst sicher auf DIN 5008 an. Verbindlich? Keine Ahnung. Typographisch vertretbar? Nicht immer. Ob ein normales Leerzeichen tragbar ist, hängt von der Schrift ab, bei nichtproportionalen Schriften ist es eh ein No-Go (`z. B.`). Wenn ich mit typographisch kompetenter Software arbeite (TeX, InDesign), verwende ich ein schmales, umbruchgeschütztes Leerzeichen (`\,`, *Thin Space*). In anderen Programmen: Unicode *U+2009* geht nicht, da umbrechend. Da das umbruchgeschützte *U+202F* nicht überall unterstützt wird, verwende ich als *vereinfachende* Schreibung meist die ohne Leerzeichen.

Comment: Das sind Fehlzitate vom Duden, wo immer ein Leerzeichen zwischen "o." und "ä."/"Ä." steht.